# from object to array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is there an easy way to go from an object to multiple objects? From this:

`var obj = { 'generics.type': 'search.type', 'wood.name': 'search.name' }`

to this:

```
var nestedObj = [ {'generics.type': 'search.type'}, {'wood.name': 'search.name'} ]
```

<strike>essentially the reverse of lodash defaults: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaults</strike>

Been looking for this for hours, and now I'm turning here... Thanks

Comment: Is 'nestedObj` supposed to be an array?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, I can't see how it's the inverse of `_.defaults`.

Comment: Yes it was supposed to be an array. forgot to mention. Have edited question

Answer (score 2):

With lodash or underscore you could use [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```
var result = _.map(obj, (v,k) => ({[k]: v}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var createDiffObjs = function(obj ){
    var nestedObj = [];
    for( var prop in obj ) {
                 var elem = {};
                 elem[ prop ] = obj [prop ];
                 nestedObj.push( elem );
                }
    return nestedObj;
}
```

And then use it thus:

```
nestedObj = createDiffObjs( obj );
```

Comment: I think you'll find that doesn't work - you can't use a variable as the key in a literal object

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something shorter, but I think the obvious solution is the only one.

```js
var obj = { 'generics.type': 'search.type', 'wood.name': 'search.name' };
var arr = _.map(obj, function(v, k) { var o = {}; o[k] = v; return o; });
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nestedObj = { {'generics.type': 'search.type'}, {'wood.name': 'search.name'} }
```

This is not a valid data structure in JavaScript. A JavaScript object is a pair of key and value.

Use an array instead for multiple objects:

```
var multipleObjs = [ {'generics.type': 'search.type'}, {'wood.name': 'search.name'} ]
```

Comment: I found out. Thanks Mia. I am looking for a way (simple/easy) to convert it into an array with nested objects. Have edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your object structure is valid or not with http://pro.jsonlint.com/

And then go to investigate ES2015=ES6 new JavaScript specifications which calls Destructuring of arrays(i.e. objects) https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/  you will find everything about new approach on JavaScript. Good Luck!!! (if your object structure would be right we could help you)